# How to generate this signal in LTspice

Tags: signal, generator

[image: Pu]

I would like to generate this signal on LTspice. Does anyone know?
(this pic is plotted from excel and matlab)

Comment: You don't say if this must be generated by supplying a sine (blue curve) and that you must generate the orange curve from it. If so, you've got three states and two thresholds to handle. If all you need to do is generate the orange waveform and don't care about the blue one, then use a one-shot PWL, a PWL file, or stack two PULSE voltage supplies for continuous. Just read the (hit F1) instructions for voltage sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, well.

Here, this provides exactly and only what you asked for:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create a continuous "modified sine wave" from two PULSE sources:

[image]

Comment: thank you .this is my need .